# Joining MySQL info and 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, inner-join

Hello StackOverflow members, I need your help to do the following.

I have 2 tables in MySQL database:

Table: **`products`**

- `product_id`
- `name`
- `long_desc`
- `price`
- `id_categorie`
- `manufacturer`
- `images`

Table: **`images`**

- `image_id`
- `path`
- `id_product`

Now I need to copy the contents of PATH COLUMN from IMAGES TABLE to PATH COLUMN in PRODUCTS TABLE **BUT** where id_product = product_id.

Lets say I have some data in PRODUCTS TABLE and IMAGES TABLE.

**PRODUCTS**

- product_id: 74
- name: Product1
- long_desc: SomeText
- price: 100.00
- id_categorie: 3
- manufacturer: Panasonic
- images: *NULL*.

**IMAGES**

- image_id: 1
- path: ./images/panasonic.jpg
- id_product: 74

I need to copy the PATH from IMAGES to IMAGES in PRODUCTS WHERE id_products from IMAGES = product_id from PRODUCTS.

The problem is I have 2500 products and I don't have time to do it manually so I need some help with doing this. Can this be done with JOIN or PHP? Need some help with this. =)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this update should work

```
UPDATE `products` `p` INNER JOIN `images` `i` ON `i`.`id_product` = `p`.`product_id` SET `p`.`images` = `i`.`path`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE PRODUCTS,IMAGES SET PRODUCTS.images = IMAGES.path WHERE IMAGES.id_products=PRODUCTS.product_ID
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE PRODUCTS 
JOIN IMAGES
ON PRODUCTS.PRODUCT_ID= IMAGES.ID_PRODUCT
SET PRODUCTS.IMAGES = IMAGES.PATH
```